# Why won't anchor tag display:block

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

here is the codepen I am working on.
[CodePen for my code](https://codepen.io/Kmax1940/pen/zYxJYmv)

I am trying to get the link in the dropdown menu to be 100% width of the container it is in.

See how it is just a short grey link right now?
I am trying to make that  tag display block so it will fill the entire width.

I have set the containing li to display:inline-block and the anchor tag to display:block....

No dice.    The anchor tag will not go to 100% width.

Any tips?

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Hover Link</a>
  <ul><li><a href="#">I should be 100%</a></li></ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Link Three</a</li>
  </ul>
```

Here is the css code:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 15px 12px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Amiko",sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color #428bca;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 13px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #a1c5e5;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: The `li` containing your anchor needs to have a `width` set on it.

Comment: @Quentin thanks.  I did not think about the codepen going away.  I just thought it would simply the question to have less code.  i have added the html.

Comment: @josh thanks!  that was it!  i was just not select the correct li.  i was not going down deep enough into the nesting.  #rookieMistake

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 15px 12px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Amiko",sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color #428bca;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left:-98px;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 13px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #a1c5e5;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Hover Link</a>
  <ul><li><a href="#">I should be 100%</a></li></ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Link Three</a</li>
  </ul>
```